Problem with opening a file in assembly program
I'm working on an assembly program using NASM on Linux. The program is supposed to open a file (which is located in the same directory and has all necessary permissions) and process its contents. However, when I run the program, it fails to open the file and outputs the following error:
Error: Could not open file.
O5

What the Program Should Do:

Check if a file name is provided as a command-line argument.
If no file is specified, print an error message and exit.
Attempt to open the specified file for reading.
If the file opens successfully, read its contents, locate the second line, and print it to the standard output.
If the file cannot be opened or read, print the corresponding error message and the error code.

The Issue:
Even though the file exists in the same directory and has read and write permissions, the program fails to open it and displays the above error message.
I suspect the issue might be related to how the file name is passed or interpreted, or there may be a mistake in the sys_open implementation.
Here is the complete code:
{
    section .data
        error_no_arg db "Error: File not specified.", 10, 0
        error_open db "Error: Could not open file.", 10, 0
        error_open_code db "Open failed with error code: ", 0
        error_read db "Error: Failed to read file.", 10, 0
        newline db 10
    
    section .bss
        buffer resb 1024
        error_code resb 4
    
    section .text
        global _start
    
    _start:
        ; Check if a file name is provided
        mov eax, [esp + 4]              ; argc
        cmp eax, 2                      ; argc >= 2
        jae open_file                   ; Proceed to open file if true
    
        ; Error: File not specified
        mov eax, 4                      ; sys_write
        mov ebx, 1                      ; stdout
        mov ecx, error_no_arg           ; Error message
        mov edx, 26                     ; Length of the message
        int 0x80
        jmp exit_program
    
    open_file:
        ; Debug: Print the file name (argv[1])
        lea ebx, [esp + 8]              ; Load address of argv[1]
        mov eax, 4                      ; sys_write
        mov ecx, ebx                    ; Pointer to file name
        mov edx, 100                    ; Limit length
        int 0x80
    
        ; Attempt to open file
        mov eax, 5                      ; sys_open
        lea ebx, [esp + 8]              ; Load address of argv[1]
        mov ecx, 0                      ; O_RDONLY
        int 0x80
    
        ; Check if the file was opened successfully
        cmp eax, 0                      ; File descriptor should be >= 0
        jl file_open_error              ; If error, handle it
    
        ; Save the file descriptor
        mov ebx, eax
    
        ; Debug: Print confirmation of file opening
        mov eax, 4                      ; sys_write
        mov ebx, 1                      ; stdout
        lea ecx, [esp + 8]              ; Pointer to file name
        mov edx, 100                    ; Limit length
        int 0x80
    
    read_file:
        mov eax, 3                      ; sys_read
        mov ecx, buffer                 ; Buffer pointer
        mov edx, 1024                   ; Bytes to read
        int 0x80
        cmp eax, 0                      ; EOF reached?
        jle file_read_error             ; If error, handle it
    
        ; Look for the second line
        mov esi, buffer                 ; esi points to the buffer
        xor ecx, ecx                    ; Line counter
    
    find_second_line:
        mov al, byte [esi]              ; Read a byte from the buffer
        cmp al, 0                       ; End of data?
        je end_of_buffer
        cmp al, [newline]               ; Check for newline
        jne skip_char
    
        inc ecx                         ; Increment line counter
        cmp ecx, 2                      ; Found the second line?
        je print_second_line
    
    skip_char:
        inc esi                         ; Next character
        jmp find_second_line
    
    print_second_line:
        ; Print the second line
        mov edx, 0                      ; Line length counter
    find_line_end:
        mov al, byte [esi + edx]
        cmp al, 0                       ; End of data?
        je do_write
        cmp al, [newline]               ; End of line?
        je do_write
        inc edx                         ; Increment line length
        jmp find_line_end
    
    do_write:
        mov eax, 4                      ; sys_write
        mov ebx, 1                      ; stdout
        lea ecx, [esi]                  ; Pointer to second line
        int 0x80
        jmp close_file
    
    end_of_buffer:
    close_file:
        ; Close the file
        mov eax, 6                      ; sys_close
        mov ebx, [esp + 4]              ; File descriptor in ebx
        int 0x80
        jmp exit_program
    
    file_open_error:
        ; Error: Could not open file
        mov eax, 4                      ; sys_write
        mov ebx, 1                      ; stdout
        mov ecx, error_open             ; Error message
        mov edx, 30                     ; Length of the message
        int 0x80
    
        ; Print error code
        mov eax, 5                      ; sys_open returns the error code in eax
        lea ebx, [error_code]           ; Pointer to error code variable
        mov [error_code], eax           ; Store the error code
        mov eax, [error_code]           ; Load the error code
        ; Convert error code to string and print
        call print_error_code
    
        jmp exit_program
    
    file_read_error:
        ; Error: Failed to read file
        mov eax, 4                      ; sys_write
        mov ebx, 1                      ; stdout
        mov ecx, error_read             ; Error message
        mov edx, 29                     ; Length of the message
        int 0x80
    
    exit_program:
        ; Exit the program
        mov eax, 1                      ; sys_exit
        xor ebx, ebx                    ; Exit code: 0
        int 0x80
    
    print_error_code:
        ; Print error code as a string
        add eax, '0'                    ; Convert error code to character
        mov [error_code], al            ; Write character to buffer
        mov eax, 4                      ; sys_write
        mov ebx, 1                      ; stdout
        lea ecx, [error_code]           ; Pointer to buffer
        mov edx, 1                      ; Output size
        int 0x80
        ret
}


In addition to the problem accessing argv[1] (covered in the answer), argc is [esp+0], not [esp+4]. [esp+4] is argv[0].

lea ebx, [esp + 8]              ; Load address of argv[1]

Nah man that's a misleading comment. The argv array is unlikely to be a filename.
mov ebx, [esp + 8]              ; Load address of argv[1]

That's more like it.

More specifically, char *argv[] is an array of pointers to strings, so each entry "is" a filename, but you need the entry itself, not a pointer to an entry (which itself is a pointer).  In C you'd do write(1, argv[1], 100) not write(1, argv + 1, 100).
